# Remove &lt; in Response body of xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

My response always shows `&lt;` for one of the values inside XML  instead of `<`.

Below is my XML MyResponseEnity:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "test")
public class MyResponseEnity implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private Result result;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String age;

}

public class Result {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private final String val = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML();
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;
}
```

The reason for not converting `&lt;` to `<`  is because of the value for:

```
@JacksonXmlText
private String value;
```

is an actual xml but in the form of a string, something like `<history>abc</history>`.

I tried adding httpmesssgaeconverters in configuration(i am using spring boot)

```
 @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml();
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }
```

Controller:

```
return new ResponseEntity<MyResponseEnity>(myResponseEnity,
        HttpStatus.OK);
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong and how can I get `&lt;` converted to <

This is my current result:

```
<test>
<result val="application/xml">&lt;history>abc&lt;/history></result>
<name>myname</name>
<age>myage</age>
</test>
```

Comment: Have you had a look to `@JsonRawValue` (works for XML as well)

Comment: Are you suggesting to try @JsonRawValue instead of JacksonXmlProperty,
 can I add namespace and attributes to XML using JsonRawValue?

Comment: I'll use both annotation but this is just a guess TBH ;)

Comment: Awesome @GaëlJ, i used jsonraw and it worked

Comment: Great, l'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@JsonRawValue` annotation to the field, which will be considered as a raw XML value when serializing.